# PIL make and save image created by list of points

Tags: python, image-processing, python-2.7

This is the input data.It's store in to var named points :

```
[(0.4972565157750343, 0.0007919756779007122), (0.4977137631458619, 0.0007919756779007174), (0.49794238683127573, 0.0011879635168510763), (0.49817101051668955, 0.0007919756779007174), (0.49862825788751713, 0.0007919756779007122), (0.4983996342021033, 0.00039598783895035877), (0.49862825788751713, 0.0), (0.4990855052583448, 0.0), (0.4993141289437586, 0.00039598783895036414), (0.49954275262917236, 0.0), (0.5, 0.0)]
```

This is my source code to make one PNG image and show.

```
width = int(TOTALWIDTH)
height = int(TOTALWIDTH*0.32)
im=Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon(points,"#993300",None)
im.resize((width, height),Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save("test-k.png", "PNG")
im.show()
```

I don't know what is wrong with this but I got this error:

```
ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 484, in _save
e.setimage(im.im, b)
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Can help me ? Regards.

Comment: var named points is very long because I use Kock Curve function. Most of this items is under 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it:
Error it's link from size image and TOTALWIDTH with has 1.
But I discover it's need to see value from Kock Curve and teh area of the image. 
This is another issue for me. 
So if you have some tutorials please send me. Thank you.